Cannot open file: extension.h, but IncludePath is set
Using VS Code launched from Visual Studio 2019 professional developer terminal (windows 11). I am trying to include torch/extension.h by including the path of the conda environment in which I have pytorch installed. In .vscode, my properties.json is the following:
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/cuda_test/lib/site-packages/torch/include",
                "C:/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/cuda_test/lib/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include"
            ]

However, when I use #include <torch/extension.h> the code doesn't compile because it can't find the file. How do I resolve this?
I have gone into the folders and the file IS there. I have tried including the full path ("C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\cuda_test\Lib\site-packages\torch\include\torch\extension.h"), while the compiler finds the file, it is unable to find the other files that exntension.h uses. I have tried including the double star to indicate recursive search, but it didn't work.

Always two there are. No more, no less. A tasks.json and a c_cpp_properties.json.

@user4581301 I only modified c_cpp_properties.json. Do I need to change task.json as well?

Do I need to change task.json as well? Yes, c_cpp_properties.json is for Intellisense only. tasks.json is for building.

Your path in JSON file:  "C:/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/cuda_test/lib/site-packages/torch/include"
Your path in the description:
"C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\cppcuda\Lib\site-packages\torch\include"
It's 2 different paths

typo on my end. I actually have torch installed in both environments.
